# HTML element in memory and display problem after inserting it to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

When we run following script under Firefox ...

```
var d = $("<div class='test'></div>");
d.hide();
$("body").prepend(d);
d.show();
```

... and look to HTML, this inserted element will have style attribute:

> style="display: block;"

Under Webkit, element will have:

> style="display: none;"

This scenario in used in a JavaScript component, i develop. This component has a collection of HTML elements in it's internal variables, and inserts they to specified destination container.

Because inserted element having display-property initialized in style attribute, it overrides CSS. This breaks the layout of a page.

As a quick solution, i can store "style" attribute, before element is inserted to the DOM, and, after inserting, write stored version over created one.

Is there any better solution ?

Why this ever happens and **how can i check, whether element is not yet inserted to the DOM** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[When I do that](http://jsbin.com/ebucu3) with either Chrome or Safari (both WebKit-based browsers), if I inspect the element with the built-in tools, it has no `style.display` property at all, and so the default `div` style of `display: block` is used. ([Here's a version](http://jsbin.com/ebucu3/2) with some text in the div, so it's easier to see and to find with the DOM inspector.)

So I suspect the problem lies elsewhere. For instance, is there intervening code that may be failing on WebKit, so that `d.show();` never ends up getting called? That would certainly explain it. Easy enough with the built-in tools in Chrome or Safari to set a breakpoint on the code creating the div and walk through it.

Re your question:

> ...how can i check, whether element is not yet inserted to the DOM ?

That question was asked here on StackOverflow just recently, and one of the answers specific to jQuery was rather elegant:

```
if (d.closest("body").length == 0) {
    // It's not in the DOM yet
}
```

---

**Update**: Re your comment below

> Look at this test page with Firefox. The div has "style=display: block;" explicitly defined. Under Webkit, it has empty style attr. I'm using built-in inspector in both Firefox and Safari.

Ah, okay, so the problem isn't a `display: none` in WebKit browsers (your statement about that in the question led me astray), but rather that Firefox (and possibly other Gecko browsers) end up having `display: block` on the element.

I'd probably approach this like this:

```
var d = $("<div class='test'></div>");
d.addClass("hidden");
$("body").prepend(d);
d.removeClass("hidden");
```

...with this CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ebucu3/3)

That way, you *know* you won't end up with a `style.display` property set at all.

---

**Update 2**: The other thing you can do is remove the `style.display` property directly:

```
var d = $("<div class='test'>Hi there</div>");
d.hide();
$("body").prepend(d);
d.show();
d[0].style.display = "";
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ebucu3/4)

You alluded to effects, so if you're doing `fadeIn` or something like that, use the callback:

```
var d = $("<div class='test'>Hi there</div>");
d.hide();
$("body").prepend(d);
d.fadeIn(function() {
    this.style.display = "";
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ebucu3/5)

Comment: Look at this test page with Firefox. The div has "style=display: block;" explicitly defined. Under Webkit, it has empty style attr. I'm using built-in inspector in both Firefox and Safari.

Comment: @AntonAL: I see what you're talking about. Updated the answer.

Comment: I've had the same idea for CSS-only effects. It works, but when we're doing removeClass(), CSS-animations will not be played. We should do it after some little interval, say, 100 milliseconds. Thanks !

Comment: @AntonAL: Had another thought, added a final update to the end. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

How about if you do

```
var d = $("<div class='test'></div>");
d.hide();
$("body").prepend(d);
d.removeAttr('style'); // this will revert to the original styling
```

Comment: It works, but it not reverts the style attr, it clears it. Thanks.

Comment: @Anton, indeed. But since your code only adds the `display:none` through the `.hide()` method, removing the style attribute returns to whatever is specified by the `.test` class.